# Laravel 5.6 won't log to Slack

Tags: laravel, slack

Currently my config/logging.php channels section contains like the following:

```
'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single', 'slack'],
    ],
```

Then in my slack section I have set a webhook using the Incoming Webhooks section in Slack. https://slack.com/apps/A0F7XDUAZ-incoming-webhooks

Other incoming webhooks I've set for other application (not Laravel) have all worked perfectly.

When I call the following:

`Log::channel('stack')->info('test');` then it successfully logs to the file, but not to Slack.

or

`Log::channel('slack')->info('test');` just seemingly does nothing.

In my Slack channels as I add the configuration I can see the notification "added an integration to this channel: Laravel Log"

Not sure what else to do to even troubleshoot this or get it working?

Comment: Do you have Guzzle installed? Did you maybe specify a minimum `level` for logging to be escalated to Slack and `info` is below that?

Comment: @TobiasK Guzzle is installed, using it for some api requests. The minimum log level was it. Didn't realize that the `level` there was minimum. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer if you want to mark this question done and don't mind giving some sweet internet points.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure `info` is not below the specified minimum `level` for messages to be escalated to Slack in `config/logging.php`.

Comment: Changing `'level' => 'debug',` in `\config\logging.php` file solved the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the channel level is **on the debug, all kinds of log functions work**.
the following levels can be used for logs in order of importance

```
1- emergency
2-alert
3-critical
4-error
5-warning
6-notice
7-info
8-debug
```

and if the level you used in the channel settings should be higher than the log level. The log does not work
For example, if the channel level settings are critical

```
Log::error($message);
Log::warning($message);
Log::notice($message);
Log::info($message);
Log::debug($message);
```

does not work
But

```
Log::emergency($message);
Log::alert($message);
Log::critical($message);
```

they are working.
So if the channel level is on the debug, all kinds of log functions work.

```
        'slack_channel' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/.....',
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
//            'level' => 'critical',///<---- in critical level it`s work for Log::channel('slack_channel')->critical('message') || alert('message') || emergency('message')
            'level' => 'debug',///<---- in debug level it`s work for each type log. for example  Log::channel('slack_channel')->debug('message') || info('message') || notice('message') .... emergency('message')

        ],
```